# TextInput font family doesn't work in React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, custom-font

I'm creating a React Native Application with React Native version: '~0.55.2'

I have two custom fonts and I have set them using `rnpm` asset declaration and linked them successfully. I use custom font family with Button and text and I didn't have issues. But when I sent font family on TextInput it works well in iOS simulator but not in Android device, it doesn't use that font. Buttons that use that custom font works but not only TextInput have the issue.

I have my Android device runs on 5.1.1.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

class KTTextInput extends Component {
  render = () => {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, this.props.containerStyle]}>
        <TextInput
          style={[styles.textInput, this.props.textStyle]}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          placeholderTextColor={EStyleSheet.value('$placeholderFontColor')}
          placeholderStyle={styles.placeholder}
          keyboardAppearance="dark"
          {...this.props}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
}

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...someStyles
  },
  textInput: {
    margin: 0,
    padding: 5,
    borderRadius: '$textInputBorderRadius',
    fontFamily: 'NotoSerifSinhala-Bold',
    backgroundColor: '#37317a',
    color: '$textInputFontColor',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    height: 40
  },
  placeholder: {
    fontFamily: 'NotoSerifSinhala-Bold'
  }
});

export default KTTextInput;
```

Comment: I recommend check font files manually at your android folder.It should placed at  "{project-root-folder}/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts" location. Also it should same name as IOS platform and android platform.Could you check and let me know what is wrong please ?

Comment: @FatihAyyildiz Yeah. It's has font in the android/app/src/main/assets/fonts. It renders that same font to Buttons and Text elements without issues.

Comment: Ok. Could you provide how you are using your component and also how you are using font Stylesheet ? can you provide some code to look specificaly.

Comment: @FatihAyyildiz updated the question

Comment: everything looks ok. You also said file names and locations are ok. May be this issue is related with that "react-native-extended-stylesheet" library. I checked issues at that library but nobody talk about font family. My recommendation is this;Just create regular stylesheet object from react-native library and set new class with fontfamily definition. Then give that class to textinput. Just make sure to irrevelant or relevant with "react-native-extended-stylesheet" styles.

Comment: @FatihAyyildiz the issue was there even before I added the extended stylesheet library. I added it later.

Comment: oh ok. Last thing, are you using ttf file or otf file at android. I checked my projects and all of my projects are using otf extension in android. May be this is affecting

Comment: @FatihAyyildiz I'm using ttf. Thanks, I will look to that too.